# AttributeError: 'LoginPage' object has no attribute 'driver'

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, selenium-webdriver

I have a base class. Inheriting base class, login.py runs without any problem. But when I run Company_Management.py its giving me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sohel/eclipse-workspace/Copell/copell/Company_Management.py", line 22, in test_company 
    em.test_logn()
  File "/home/sohel/eclipse-workspace/Copell/copell/login.py", line 15, in test_logn
    driver =self.driver
AttributeError: 'LoginPage' object has no attribute 'driver'
```

What I am trying to do is that, when I will run Company_Management.py it will excute `test_logn(self)` method first then will click on 2 urls from xpath.

### base.py

```
import unittest
import time
from selenium import webdriver

class Login(unittest.TestCase):
   @classmethod
   def setUpClass(cls):
       cls.driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/sohel/eclipse-workspace/chromedriver')   
       cls.driver.maximize_window()
       cls.driver.get("https:www.car.com/login?back_url=%2F")
       time.sleep(3) 


   @classmethod 
   def tearDownClass(cls):
       cls.driver.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
unittest.main()
```

### login.py

```
import base
import unittest
import time

class LoginPage(base.Login):

    def test_logn(self):
        driver =self.driver
        driver.find_element_by_id("email").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_id("email").send_keys("keya@gmail.com")
        driver.find_element_by_id("password").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_id("password").send_keys("Abcd1234")
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type='submit']").click()

    def test_logout(self):    
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[9]/a/span").click()        

if __name__ == '__main__':
unittest.main()
```

### Company_Management.py

```
import base
import unittest
import login
import logging
import time

class CompanyManagement(base.Login):

    def test_company(self):
        driver = self.driver

        em = login.LoginPage()
        em.test_logn()

        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ec-ui-side-bar/div/div/ul/li[3]/a/span").click()
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ec-ui-side-bar/div/div/ul/li[3]/ul/li/a/span").click()    
        time.sleep(3)              

if __name__ == '__main__':
unittest.main()
```

ERROR: test_company (copell.Company_Management.CompanyManagement) ---------------------------------------------------------------------- Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/sohel/eclipse-workspace/Copell/copell/Company_Management.py", line 22, in test_company em.test_logn() File "/home/sohel/eclipse-workspace/Copell/copell/login.py", line 15, in test_logn driver =self.driver AttributeError: 'LoginPage' object has no attribute 'driver' --------------------------------------------------------------------- Ran 1 test in 7.227s FAILED (errors=1)

Comment: Which line throws the error? Please post the stacktrace.

Comment: Don't place code in comments. Please edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both your classes extend [[Python 2]: *class* unittest.**TestCase**(*methodName='runTest'*)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase). 
According to [[Python 2]: Skipping tests and expected failures](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#skipping-tests-and-expected-failures)

> Skipped tests will not have `setUp()` or `tearDown()` run around them. Skipped classes will **not** have `setUpClass()` or `tearDownClass()` run.

Also, according to [[Python 2]: setUpClass and tearDownClass](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#setupclass-and-teardownclass):

> If you want the `setUpClass` and `tearDownClass` on base classes called then **you** must call up to them yourself.

What happens:

- *login.py*: *LoginPage* is instantiated (and run) automatically by the *unittest* framework (`unittest.main()`) and *setUpClass* method is called -
  which adds the *driver* attribute to the *LoginPage* class - and (automatically, to) all its instances
- *Company_Management.py*: *LoginPage* is instantiated *manually* by you (`em = login.LoginPage()`), but the *setUpClass* method isn't called - and thus *LoginPage* (or any of its instances) **doesn't have** the *driver* attribute - hence your error. 
  To fix it, manually call the method yourself, either:

  - After instantiating the class (on the instance):

    ```py
    em = login.LoginPage()
    em.setUpClass()
    ```
  - On the class itself (better, before instantiating it)

    ```py
    login.LoginPage.setUpClass()
    em = login.LoginPage()
    ```