# AttributeError: 'TestLogin' object has no attribute 'driver'

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, appium, pageobjects

So, my question is related to [AttributeError: 'LoginPage' object has no attribute 'driver'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49149491/attributeerror-loginpage-object-has-no-attribute-driver), but answer doesn't solve my issue.

I'm creating test cases using Python and Appium framework with page object  model and I need some code to be executed before every test case, so I use `setUp` method for this in base_test.py file.

**base_test.py**

```
class BaseTest(object):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Remote(server_url,device_config)
        self.os = str(self.driver.caps['platformName']).lower()
```

TestLogin class extends BaseTest class.

**test_login.py**

```
class TestLogin(BaseTest):
    def __init__(self):
        self.login_page = LoginPage(self.driver)

    def test_00_login(self):
        self.login_page.openLoginPage()
```

LoginPage class needs `driver` object because all actions happen in page classes.

If I execute this script I get an error `AttributeError: 'TestLogin' object has no attribute 'driver'`.

Now, if I change my TestLogin class to:

```
class TestLogin(BaseTest):
    def __init__(self):
        setup = BaseTest()
        setup.setUp()
        self.login_page = LoginPage(setup.driver)

    def test_00_login(self):
        self.login_page.openLoginPage()
```

I won't receive an error but `setUp` method will be executed 2 times, first on `setup.setUp()` and then in `test_00_login(self)` method. This is not what I want.

Third way would be to move `self.login_page = LoginPage(self.driver)` to the method `test_00_login(self)`, but this way I would need to have `self.login_page = LoginPage(self.driver)` in every future method I write in TestLogin class.

```
class TestLogin(BaseTest):
    def test_00_login(self):
        self.login_page = LoginPage(self.driver)
        self.login_page.openLoginPage()
```

Is there a way of having `self.login_page = LoginPage(self.driver)` on top level of TestLogin class, like in `__init__(self)` method, but without getting attribute error? I need a better way of handling it.

Thank you.

Comment: I think you may solve your problem initializing your driver in the __init__ method, and then initializing the superclass; but it's pretty hard to produce an answer because you didn't provide a [mcve]. If you're able to provide something replicable, i'll be glad to help

Answer (score -1):

i found other answer for you , you must define self.driver before everything:

```
from webdriver import Remote
import webdriver 

self = webdriver
driver  = Remote(server_url,device_config)

class BaseTest(object):
def setUp(self):
    self.os = str(self.driver.caps['platformName']).lower()

class TestLogin(BaseTest):
    def __init__(self):
        self.login_page = LoginPage(self.driver)

    def test_00_login(self):
        self.login_page.openLoginPage()

    class TestLogin(BaseTest):
       def test_00_login(self):
         self.login_page = LoginPage(self.driver)
         self.login_page.openLoginPage()
```

then what ever you want , don't forget to define other syntaxs

Comment: the setUp method implies this is a unitTest test cast, steps of SetUp are supposed to run automatically in any subclasses.  i believe this is still sort of unresolved as i ran into the same issue myself. I think the link in the OP has hints towards the proper solution, but i'm still working on the issue myself.